# What VS 2010 project for a plain HTML and JS project

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2010

What VS 2010 project template would you use for a plain HTML and JS project, no ASP or other code. Just plain vanilla HTML / JS. I am using an empty Web project ("ASP.net empty Web Application"), still giving me unnecessary files and directories. Is there anything better?

This question is **not** about extensions for JS, such as [Visual Studio Javascript extensions feature comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204032/visual-studio-javascript-extensions-feature-comparison) .

-- Update as of 15. August --

I have deleted the extra directories and references to the extend possible. The `bin` folder gets recreated whenever the application is build, but I can solve this on Solution level by switching of the build (Configuration properties). The `webconfig` is required for debugging - I cannot get rid of this one - so this is the best I get until now.

**Damn** - `obj` and `bin` directories **are recreated when closing and re-opening VS2010** (preparing solution stage). So I have to live with some overhead of files / directories.

-- As of 18.August --
Guess there is no better way, delete as much as possible and live with the remaining "trash".

Comment: Just delete the extra files :)

Comment: There's nothing built in that fits that need really. You could always customize a different project once, then store it as a template, if it's a common thing for you.

Comment: I ll crosscheck this, hope the missing file will not cause any side effects. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Visual Studio Web Development** is orientated to **ASP.NET projects creation**, but you can build without any problem, **HTML & JS applications** **deleting the extra directories** created for ASP.NET apps, which need that.

Best regards.
Ángel Manuel.

Comment: As of my comment above, the files can not really be deleted. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered creating a web site in visual studio instead of using a web project? File -> New -> Web Site. It's still directed towards asp.net development but it might be more what you are looking for.

Comment: This is actually what I am using "ASP.net empty Web Application".

Comment: There is a Web Site type, as Paul suggested. Select File | New | Web Site... | ASP.NET Empty Web Site, NOT File | New Project | ASP.net empty Web Application

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use a text editor/hilighter like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) :P

Comment: ok, point taken, however in my case I will / want to use VS2010 for some reasons. I am only looking for the best template, not an alternative IDE

Comment: Then like all the others said, I'd just delete the extra files before publishing :) there's no necessity in using the actual ASP tools in VS10