# Visual Studio 2010 as simple web site editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to use Visual Studio 2010 as a simple web site editor (HTML + JavaScript; no ASP.NET)?

VS only supports known project file types (i.e. .csproj), so I started with a C# project and I've been fiddling with the file, but VS still keeps creating .vshost files and obj directory.

Can I force it not to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052113/what-vs-2010-project-for-a-plain-html-and-js-project)

*Visual Studio Web Development is orientated to ASP.NET projects creation, but you can build without any problem, HTML & JS applications deleting the extra directories created for ASP.NET apps, which need that.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using Visual Web developer

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/9z74w20y

Answer (score 0):

You can add "Project Folders" to a empty project / solution and add the files into the folders without any project "overhead" .. intellisense works fine ..